# Conditionally manipulate elements' properties in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to javascript and trying to learn some basic with toy examples.

Say I have an array containing data on six people.

```
const myArray = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": 4},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": 5},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": 6},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": 1},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": 2}
];
```

The array lists each person's `id`, `value`, and who they're `friends` with. E.g., Person 1 is friends with person 3, and person 3 is friends with person 5, and so on.

Now I want to manipulate who is friends with who based on each person's value. This is the logic I'd like to implement (probably in a for loop):

**IF** person's value is the *lowest* or the *second lowest* value in the array,
**THEN** add the id of the person with the *highest* value in the array to their friends.

So my desired output in this case is:

```
const myArray = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": [4, 1]},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": 5},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": 6},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": 1},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": [2, 1]}
];
```

How can I do this?

---

I've done a very basic manipulation of the array below, where I take away the friend of the person with the highest value in the array. But I've gotten confused as I've moved onto this more complicated task.

```js
const myArray = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": 4},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": 5},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": 6},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": 1},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": 2}
];

// Finds max and min values in array
var highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var tmp;
for (var i=myArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    tmp = myArray[i].value;
    if (tmp > highest) highest = tmp;
};

for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    // If person has the highest value in the array
      if(myArray[i].value == highest){
        // Then take away their friend
        myArray[i].friends = NaN
      } else {
        myArray[i].friends = myArray[i].friends
      }
  };

  console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass your source array once to figure out the highest, the lowest and the second lowest values (along with corresponding `id`'s), then modify your source array accordingly when you reach the end:

```js
const src = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": 4},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": 5},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": 6},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": 1},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": 2}
],
    
    populateFriends = input => {
      let highest = {value: -Infinity},
          lowest = {value: Infinity},
          secondLowest = {}
      for({id, value} of input){
          if(value > highest.value){
            highest = {id, value}
          } else if(value < lowest.value){
            secondLowest = {...lowest}
            lowest = {id, value}
          }
      }
      return input.map(o => 
        (o.id == lowest.id || o.id == secondLowest.id) && 
        o.friends != highest.id ? 
        {...o, friends: [o.friends, highest.id]} :
        o)
    }
    
console.log(populateFriends(src))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it so

```js
const myArray = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": 4},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": 5},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": 6},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": 1},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": 2}
];

const highestValue = myArray.reduce((acc, rec) => {
  return (acc.value < rec.value) ? acc = rec : acc
}, myArray[0])

const twoLowestPersons = myArray.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value).slice(0, 2)

const result = myArray.map(rec => {
  const object = twoLowestPersons.find(el => el.id === rec.id)
  if (typeof object !== 'undefined') {
    rec.friends = [rec.friends, highestValue.id]
    return rec
  } else {
    return rec
  }
}).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: Using `.sort()` to get 2 lowest values is a bad decision which may slow down the performance [drastically](https://jsbench.me/v8kdymcpnf/1).