# How to remove duplicate property values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, duplicates

I have an array with 6 elements. Each elements has 3 properties: `id`, `value`, and `friends`.

In my code I manipulate the array by adding new values to certain elements' `friends` property, but in some circumstances this leads to duplicate values in the `friends` property. For instance, in `myArray` below, element 5 cannot be friends with element 1 twice -- they're either friends or not.

```
const myArray = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": 4},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": 5},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": [6, 1]},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": [1, 1]},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": [2, 1]}
];
```

How can I remove duplicate values in the `friends` property in `myArray`?

My desired output would look like this:

```
const myArray = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": 4},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": 5},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": [6, 1]},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": 1},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": [2, 1]}
];
```

---

I'm new to javascript and not sure where to start with this. My intuition was to first get all the `friends` and then apply some filtering function:

```
const friendList = myArray.map(getFriends);
var uniqueFriends = [...new Set(friendList)];
```

But this clearly doesn't work.

Comment: Your intuition was good, but the changes aren't done in-place.

Comment: There's no need to clean up that side-effect, you may use [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63451078/11299053) free of that issue

Comment: Thanks @Yevgen Gorbunkov! Just noticed the edit and gave you the answer on that post. But I'll also leave this post up as it could be helpful in future.

Comment: @user72716 You need to loop through the array and make changes to friends property as needed. See my code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myArray.map(elem => {
  if(typeof(elem.friends) == 'object') {
    elem.friends = [... new Set(elem.friends)]
    if(elem.friends.length == 1) {
      elem.friends = elem.friends[0]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
const myArray = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": 4},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": 5},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": [6, 1]},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": [1, 1]},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": [2, 1]}
];

const friendList = myArray.map(getFriends);

function getFriends(element) {
  if(element.friends.length > 0) {
      element.friends = [... new Set(element.friends)]
      if(element.friends.length === 1) {
        element.friends =  element.friends[0];
      }
   }
   return element;
}


console.log(friendList);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution to this problem is to always represent the `friends` value with a set. So your array would look like this:

```
const myArray = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": new Set([3])},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": new Set([4])},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": new Set([5])},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": new Set([6, 1])},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": new Set([1, 1])},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": new Set([2, 1])}
];
```

And then to add a friend, all you have to do is:

```
myArray[i]["friends"].add(7);
```

And duplicates are handled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to perform the clean-up.

```js
const myArray = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 75, "friends": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 40, "friends": 4},
    {"id": 3, "value": 60, "friends": 5},
    {"id": 4, "value": 62, "friends": [6, 1]},
    {"id": 5, "value": 55, "friends": [1, 1]},
    {"id": 6, "value": 33, "friends": [2, 1]}
];

const getDataWithoutDup = (data) => {
  // Loop through the array
  data.forEach(val => {

   // Check if friends property in the object is an array
   if(typeof(val.friends) == 'object') {
   let newVal = [...new Set(val.friends)];

   // Add the new value of friends
   val.friends = newVal.length > 1 ? newVal : newVal[0];
   }
  })
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

getDataWithoutDup(myArray);
```